# How to add a condition in GROUP BY based on the number of rows with a certain column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this table:

```
-------------------------
| id | user_id | status |
-------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 1      |
-------------------------
| 2  | 1       | 0      |
-------------------------
| 3  | 1       | 1      |
-------------------------
| 4  | 2       | 1      |
-------------------------
| 5  | 2       | 0      |
-------------------------
```

Basically I want to select all the users (grouped by `user_id` obviously), where the number of `1` statuses and the number of `0` statuses are not the same. For the above sample data, it would return me `user_id` 1 only, as user 1 has 2 `1` statuses, and 1 `0` status. It would not return me `user_id` 2, as user 2 as 1 `1` status, and 1 `0` status, effectively cancelling each other out.

I was thinking of some condition which allowed me to use `COUNT` with a condition, but I'm not sure how that can be done.

Comment: Look at HAVING clause.

Comment: @MichałSznurawa I don't see how that will work for me, though. The `HAVING` clause will still mean I have to use a condition, and I'm not sure how to get that condition written.

Comment: You need to group and apply condition for result of aggregate function, and that is this what HAVING does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `HAVING()` clause with `CASE EXPRESSION`

```
SELECT t.user_id
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN 1 END) <>
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 0 THEN 1 END)
```

This will basically check for each group, that the count of `status = 1` is different from the count of `status = 0`

MySQL allows Boolean expression , so the `HAVING()` clause could be written as:

```
HAVING sum(t.status = 1) <> sum(t.status = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (simpler) solution to check if both statuses got an equal count:

```
SELECT t.user_id
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) <> 0
```